# white space above page cannot be removed

Tags: wordpress, header, wordpress-theming, elementor

There is a very annoying white bar at the top of my page (Ocean WP theme). I have disabled topbar in the the theme settings, so it should not be there because of that. I also have not found any global margin settings or similar.

Please, please help to end my suffering[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's the admin bar.

**Users** -> **Profile** -> and uncheck **Show Toolbar when viewing site**

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution: In the theme settings (Appearance - customize - general options - general settings) the top and bottom margins should be set to zero if such gaps are not wanted.